# how to use a virtual function again in an inherited class

Tags: c++

I have 3 classes namely

```
class A;
class B;
class C : public B {
};
```

Now i want to use some member functions in `C`, that have been made virtual in `A` and have been overridden in `B`.  When I try to access a member of `A` from `C` it gives an error saying that C is not a direct base class of A.

What should I do? Should I write that piece of code again?

I searched other sites and got confused answers which ruined my concepts of inheritance, so please give a descriptive but clear answer

Comment: Can you share code that you have tried?

Comment: Instead of describing your code in text, which might be hard to understand, why not show some actual code? Preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are you saying you want C to use A's implementation that is overridden in B?

Comment: _'... which ruined my concepts of inheritance ...'_ May be there are flaws in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear. Are you asking how to call `A`'s or `B`'s version of the function? If so, you could do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    virtual void Foo () {
        std::cout << "A::Foo()" "\n" ;
    }
};

struct B : public A
{
    void Foo () {
        std::cout << "B::Foo()" "\n" ;
    }
};

struct C : public B
{
    void Foo () {
        std::cout << "C::Foo()" "\n" ;
    }
};

int main (void)
{
    C c ;
    c.A::Foo () ;
    c.B::Foo () ;
    c.Foo () ;

    A *p1 = &c ;
    p1->Foo () ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

Output:

> > A::Foo()
> >     B::Foo()
> >     C::Foo()
> >     C::Foo()

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
class A {
  public:
    virtual int f() { return 42; }
};

class B : public A {
  public:
    int f() { return 0; }
};

class C : public B {
  public:
    int g() { return f(); }
};
```

There is nothing special to do.

Comment: actually if u read more carefully I said that C is inherited from both A and B

Comment: @user3443251 As is is here. `C` is derived from `B`, so it is also derived from `A`.

Comment: but when i want to access a member of A from C it gives an error saying that A is not a direct base class of C

Comment: To access a member of A you can be specific and say: `return A::f();`

Comment: @YoungJohn and if i want to access a protected member?

Comment: Are you using protected inheritance then? if B inherits from A publicly, and C inherits from B publicly, then C has the same access to A as B.

Comment: As long as B is not inheriting from A privately, then when C inherits from B, C can access protected members from both A and B.

Answer (score 1):

```
void C::f() { return A::f(); }
```

Won't this be enough?

Answer (score 0):

> What should I do? Should I write that piece of code again?

You can always explicitly refer to methods declared in `class A` as long they are visible from your inheritance protection scope:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void foo() {}
};

class B : public A {
public:
    virtual void foo() { 
        // do something else
    }
};

class C : public B {
public:
    virtual void foo() { 
        // use A's implementation again
        A::foo();
    }
};
```